PrimeFaces Theme Designer Stuck on "Setting up..." – How to Fix?
I'm trying to use the PrimeFaces Theme Designer to customize the theme for my JSF application, but when I load the Theme Designer, it gets stuck on the "Setting up..." screen and never progresses. I've waited for several minutes, tried reloading the page, and checked my internet connection, but nothing seems to work.
Steps I've taken so far:
Cleared browser cache and cookies
Tried different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)
Disabled browser extensions
Restarted my machine

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and how can I resolve it? Is there a specific log or configuration I should check?
Thanks in advance!

PrimeTek is taking down that theme designer. They mentioned on the website it should not still be up.

Thank you, @Melloware, for the clarification and for pointing me to the PrimeTek discussion. I’ll check it out and see what options are available. Could you please guide me to the PrimeTek website? Appreciate the guidance!

Yep see: https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/2315
